# Next JS 13 notFound() returns with status 200 instead of 404

Tags: next.js

We have a dynamic page inside my `/app` folder: `/app/[...slug]`.

We're generating a bunch of static urls. Inside of the component there is a check, if such url exists. If not, `notFound` function is fired.

```
if (!databaseId) notFound();
```

And it works fine in the way, that if there is no such page in the backend, then the component from the `not-found.tsx` is rendered. Well, it works fine when we use `export const dynamicParams = false;`, so there is no SSR check, if the path is not found. But without that, the SSR check is fired and while the `notFound` function still renders the component from the `not-found.tsx`, but the status of the returned page in the Network tab in Chrome is 200. Why is this happening? If the `notFound` is fired in the backend in this case, then shouldn't it automaticaly add a 404 status to the response? Or are we missing something along the way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering my own question - this comment helped me: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51021#issuecomment-1645492229.

> I was using an instant loading state (loading.tsx file on the same
> level as the page.tsx). I don't know the specifics, but it does make
> sense because the loading appears before anything else, so the server
> needs to send some status code.